# Installation of the mysqlclient module on the Windows system

Tags: mysql, django, libmysqlclient

**I am use Windows 10 system, for my Django project when I try to download,
I install mysqlclient module but not working it displays errors.**

> *when i write command pip install mysqlclient that this error are see.*
>
> ```
> Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB) Using legacy setup.py
> install for mysqlclient, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
> Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
>     Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
>     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>      command: 'c:\users\sachin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe'
> -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sachin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ye9s3zyg\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';
> __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sachin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ye9s3zyg\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\sachin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yz3e0ytd\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\sachin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include\mysqlclient'
>          cwd: C:\Users\sachin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ye9s3zyg\mysqlclient\
>     Complete output (29 lines):
>     running install
>     running build
>     running build_py
>     creating build
>     creating build\lib.win32-3.7
>     creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>     copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>     copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>     copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>     copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>     copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>     copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>     copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>     creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
>     copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
>     copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
>     copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
>     copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
>     Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(2,1,1,'final',0)
> ```

Comment: You can format you output log with "code" formatting so it's easier to read. It's very hard to read your error at the moment. Also, it looks like your error output is not complete.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal:

```
pipenv install 
pipenv install mysqlclient
```

Comment: when you do that time in your project create two files -> PIpfile & Pipfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

step 1: first download pipenv

> `pip install pipenv`

step2: secondly install pipenv

> `pipenv install`

step3: finally install mysqlclient

> `pipenv install mysqlclient`